# Creating schema problem getting started with doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working on a tutorial with reference to the doctrine documentation. There was a problem during the process.

> php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create

result:

```
dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd "../doctrine/orm/bin" && pwd)

if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ] && [[ $(which php) == $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/* ]]; then
   # We are in Cgywin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
   dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
fi

"${dir}/doctrine" "$@" doctrine
```

I need help! Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove 'php' from the head.

`./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create`

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is [`*/doctrine-module <command>`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/cli.md)

> `php vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create`

`vendor/bin/doctrine` is [something else](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/tools.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I tried
`php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create`
it's successful.

Comment: Yea that's the same as in my answer. Have a look in that location, you'll find 4 files, which, when you've read through them, will end up going to the same entry point. Just that there's support for various usage methods. The file `doctrine.bat` is the one copied to the `vendor/bin/doctrine-module` location during installation with composer.